# How to stop sending var/log/syslog from filebeat to logstash

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, devops, elastic-stack, filebeat

Below is my filebeat.yml file where it should send logs only from the below mentioned **/home/ubuntu/logs/test-app/path.log** path. But it is all the logs including **var/log/syslog** and **/var/log/auth.log** folders. Please give me clarification on how to avoid sending system logs.

**filebeat.yml**

```
filebeat.inputs:

- type: syslog
  enabled: false
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - home/ubuntu/logs/test-app/path.log

logging:
level: info
to_files: true
to_syslog: false

filebeat.config.modules:
path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
reload.enabled: false

output.logstash:
hosts: ["ip:5044"]
```

Comment: while trying this Syslog enabled: false isn't working. let me know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check if you are enabling the system module ,

> filebeat modules list | head

> cat /etc/filebeat/modules.d/system.yml

and use filestream input instead of logs as the latter will be deprecated

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/8.2/filebeat-input-filestream.html